# setPropertiesToFetch returns 'Invalid keypath expression' error

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to use the group-by core data functionality in its most basic form:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSExpression *reviewNumKeyExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"review_num"];
    NSExpression *reviewMaxExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:reviewNumKeyExpression]];

    NSExpressionDescription *maxReviewED = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [maxReviewED setName:@"maxReview"];
    [maxReviewED setExpression:reviewMaxExpression];
    [maxReviewED setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSAttributeDescription *groupId = [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"group_id"];
    NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupId, maxReviewED, nil];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];
    [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:propertiesToFetch];
...
```

When running this code, I get the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath expression
>   ((), name maxReview,
>   isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity (null), renamingIdentifier
>   maxDepartment, validation predicates ( ), warnings ( ),
>   versionHashModifier (null)  userInfo { }) passed to
>   setPropertiesToFetch

I guess I am missing something with the API, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error message is wrong: the problem is in the `setPropertiesToGroupBy`, not the `setPropertiesToFetch`.  You cannot group by a computed value (`maxReview`), but I doubt you actually want to: if you want the maximum value of `review_num` for each `groupId`, you only need `groupId` in the `propertiesToGroupBy`:

```
NSAttributeDescription *groupId = [entity.propertiesByName objectForKey:@"group_id"];
NSArray *propertiesToFetch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupId, maxReviewED, nil];
NSArray *propertiesToGroupBy = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:groupId, nil];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:propertiesToFetch];
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:propertiesToGroupBy];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it seems that for some reason you must also have all fetched properties in the group by clause , see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935618/group-by-in-core-data-in-ios-swift-not-working .

Comment: Ok, so it seems I really do need to provide all fetch properties to the group-by EXCEPT for the computed value (maxReview)... Otherwise I get:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'SELECT clauses in queries with GROUP BY components can only contain properties named in the GROUP BY or aggregate functions ((<NSAttributeDescription: ...>), name group_name, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity Group, renamingIdentifier group_name, validation predicates