# Why set resultType property on NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Consider creating NSFetchRequest initialised with `NSDictionary` as resultType:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSDictionary>(entityName: "Student")
```

My question is why do we still need to set the resultType to `NSDictionary`. Why this field does not get set automatically when the fetch request is initialised with `NSDictionary`

```
fetchRequest.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
```

Again, same question for the following: why need second line:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSNumber>(entityName: "Employee")
fetchRequest.resultType = .countResultType
```

Answer (score 1):

Core Data was originally written in Objective C, at a time when it didn't used to have generics.

Answer (score 0):

That is used for more advanced queries, like order/group by. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972710/7715250